# CakePHP rookie question, The requested URL /pages/andy was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, apache2

I am installing CakePHP for the first time, I am running LAMP on Ubuntu 10.04LTS. Not only am I a CakePHP rookie, I am a Linux rookie as well. I found installation instructions online and I thought i had everything setup correctly. When i go to localhost i get the default CakePHP page and everything is green.

The problem is when i created a generic page called andy.ctp in the /var/www/app/views/pages folder, when i try to go to localhost/pages/andy I get a 404 NOT FOUND page that says "The requested URL /pages/andy was not found on this server."

I am sure i missed something on the initial setup, i just cant find out what. I have Googled the error and have yet to find anything to get me along. Below is my default file. Please let me know if there is anything else you need to see. Thanks for the help in advance!

is there something in the .htaccess file that might need to be changed?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/app/webroot
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try a few things first:

1. Do you have the whole CakePHP package installed under one same directory. I say so because I saw you have `/var/www/app`, and the cake directory must also be within `/var/www/`. Even when you have these directories allright, I recommend that you set the whole CakePHP package into another subdirectory, like `/var/www/your_project/app`. This will enable you to add more projects easily as time go. Also, you might want to set the Document Root to a home-level directory (i.e. `/home/your_name/www/your_project` so that you can handle file permissions more easy.
2. Do you have mod_rewrite enabled? It is required by Cake. Do a Google search; there are plenty of tutorials.

Let me know if any of these work.

---

Followup:

Hello again.

If you are seeing the default CakePHP start page with all green notices ([see this old screenshot](http://www.goredmonster.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/cakephp_designers_01-300x234.png)), then it means that you dont have anything wrong with mod_rewrite or htaccess. However, I reproduced the steps you took along with your virtualhost configuration file and found two issues:

1) You are pointing the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/app/webroot` when it should point to the top-level directory, in this case `/var/www/` (i.e. the directory where CakePHP's topmost index.php is). Also, be sure to have this directive: `DirectoryIndex index.php`

2) You are not closing the `<VirtualHost>` tag; though this can actually be a wrong copy+paste here in S.O.

Overall, try to 'debug' your VirtualHost file by starting with just a few lines so that you have to worry less about misconfigurations. I use these few for any project in my local machine, and I've had multiple CakePHP Projects all running under Apache for Ubuntu.

`<VirtualHost dummysite.com:80>

    ServerName dummysite.com

    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot "/home/yamir/Programming/Projects/dummysite"

    DirectoryIndex index.php

    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog "/home/yamir/Programming/Projects/dummysite/logs/error.log"

    CustomLog "/home/yamir/Programming/Projects/dummysite/logs/access.log" combined

</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i do have mod_rewrite enabled. I do have the whole cake package in my root /var/www, file permissions has been a pain in the butt. I'll move the files once i can get it working. Any other suggestions why it would not recognize the views/pages folder? COuld it be with .htaccess? Thanks

Comment: See my followup in the original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i changed 1 and when i did that I lost all the formatting to the cakephp page. 2. you are correct, i copied and pasted the file wrong. Does this need to be modified in any way? <Directory /var/www/> thanks

Comment: I found this in the documentation- webroot:In a production setup, this folder should serve as the document root for your application. That is how i setup the Virtualhost.

Comment: Try dealing with a small VirtualHost file like the one I posted and point DocumentRoot to the topmost directory. Frankly, it's all I can suggest, not being with your machine. Good luck. :)

Comment: ill give it a shot. Also, would I add this to my sites-available, sites-enabled or both? and would they be in there along with the default files? And i did move the folder to my home directory as you requested. Thanks

Comment: Here is what I recommend when editing virtual hosts: 1) sudo a2dissite yoursitename.com, 2) Edit the files in sites-available, 3) sudo a2ensite yoursitename.com, 4) sudo service apache2 restart. All these commands are for Ubuntu. And btw, you don't have to configure static pages (like andy.ctp) in the pages controller. Cake knows that when you use `/pages/whatever`, it will point to whatever.ctp in the view. But this is only for the pages controller.

Comment: Thanks, beleive it or not but just changing my directory to <Directory /var/www/app/> got it working. Any suggestions why? Thanks for all of your help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: The thing is that CakePHP has one htaccess file for each dir level in `/app/webroot/`. Look at them, and you'll see how they end up redirecting to the `/app/webroot/index.php` file, which starts the whole Dispatcher process (for 'executing' urls). However, I _believe_ that your htaccess files were not being read (or one of them is missing), because when you pointed the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/app/`, the index.php file in that dir actually includes the one inside `/app/webroot/index.php`. Anyway, glad you got it working. If you get stuck again AND the manual doesn't help you, be sure to post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you definitely turned on mod_rewrite?

Comment: yes, i used sudo a2enmode rewrite, i tried it a second time just for the verification that stated it has already been enabled. Any Suggestions?

Comment: and you have defined andy() in the pages controller?

Comment: php include path of /var/www/app/ ?

Comment: I have to log into my work machine and the connection is down, i wont be able to check until tomorrow. I think i didn't setup the controller correctly, where are you referencing to include the path to the controller? Thanks for the help

Comment: ok, I'm not sure how to configure the controller, i checked the controller folder and it was empty.